# Problem While Fetching the Entity data and its related Entity data with JPA(Lazy Initialization Exception)

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa, jpql

Method threw 'org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException' exception. Cannot evaluate com.esewa.admin.domain.Departments$HibernateProxy$ekCkdrrd.toString()

While i was fetching the entity its data is coming perfectly fine but the related mapping data could not able to fetch though my mapping in manytoone and its default fetch type is eager and also to ensure more in service level transactional annotation is used but the api is fetching this error.
Method threw 'org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException' exception. Cannot evaluate com.esewa.admin.domain.Departments$HibernateProxy$ekCkdrrd.toString()

Comment: Hello , can you add an exemple of your code where you fetch data and the code of Entity please ? Can you also share your application.properties or application.yaml please ?